# CLion external tools macro

Tags: python, clion

I have a project which compiles several executables for embedded systems. Each executable is generated by making an appropriate target:

- firmware1.bin
- firmware2.bin
- ...

Now I want to automate the firmware flashing process. I have a python script that can flash firmware to the embedded system flash. To call this script, I have to create additional targets:

- firmware1.bin
- firmware1.bin_upload
- firmware1.bin
- firmware1.bin_upload
- ...

This is not very convenient, so I want to create CLion external tool that calls the python script:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot find a way to pass the current target executable to the external tool in CLion. There is no macro for generated firmwares.

Is there any way to pass an external tool path to firmware? Or maybe other way to automate the uploading process except creating additional targets?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible at the time of writing;
I previewed all macros and I did not see the name of the executable/target as registered in CMake.

Here's a list of things you may be able to do instead:

- Parse your CmakeLists.txt and determine the executables being created from your python script, to which the source directory is passed.
- Try to solve it completely in CMake; which may very well be possible
- Register a feature request with CLion team, and inform me, as I will immediately +1 it.
- Write a CLion plugin (provided it can gather the info required)

I hope you managed to resolve your workflow by now.